# Paint path in Google Maps API v2

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to paint a path in Google Maps, using the new API v2 of Android Google Maps, but I don't know how can I do it.

At this moment, I'm using the gps, and for each provider update, I get a marker on my map, but I would like to paint a path instead of a marker.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this section of the API.  I haven't tried it yet but it looks like you pass a set of LatLng's and it draws lines between the points.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lines

Comment: I tried it and...it works but, it's a little bit weird because it is too much "artificial"? I meant.. you have the line drawn on your map, but it doesn't fit the real "line" that you have in the google map.

Have anybody used this method to do it? or another one?

Thanks